# how to convert textview into image with exact size like screenshot

Tags: java, android, image, android-layout

I am new in android developing and I am trying to convert or screenshot a text view into an image, lately I found a snippet code for this problem and it work fine with me when the text is very small like one sentence with one line and small text size, but if there are more than one line or big text size it gives the image with the text compressed in one line and the size of the text becomes very small.
Here is the java code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ImageView bmImage;
TextView view;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.screen);
    bmImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);

    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

    view.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
            View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));

    view.layout(0, 0, view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight());

    view.buildDrawingCache(true);
    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());
    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

    bmImage.setImageBitmap(b);
    bmImage.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
}}
```

and here is the xml code.

```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.jarad.c_to_i.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/screen"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:text="My name is Mo7mdech I am 30 years old, please help my in this problemَ"
    />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
 </LinearLayout>
```

please help, thanks.

Comment: Save screen as an image than crop it by coordinates of your Textview? I know its not an answer but i believe this will work

Comment: I thought about it but I want solve it by my code because I am sure I missed something.. thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

You could try to draw the same text into a new Canvas by hand. You can get the textPaint by `TextView.getTextPaint()`.

Answer (score 0):

I found what I did wrong ..
I made the text with width -> match_parent and the height -> wrap_content  and I think that is not giving me the exact size of the text in the image I don't know exactly why (I think the problem in width with no fixed number) but what I did lately is giving the text a fixed width and the image start giving me the same width of the text so I change the image height to -> wrap_content and it start to give me a copy of the text as a screenshot and that's what I want for now.
I know it is not the perfect solution specially with any device with width less than I put to the text but it gave me till now what I want.

Please if anyone have a better answer don't hesitate to respond.

this is my new code ..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/screen"
android:padding="6dp"
tools:context="com.jarad.c_to_i.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="370dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:text="My name is Mo7mdech I am 30 years old, please help my in this problem"
    />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```